# How to make puppeteer work through socks5 proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, headless, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I bought a proxy server version of socsk5. 
In all manuals the same example

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: {...winSize},
    args: [
        '--proxy-server=socks5://proxyhost:8000',
        '--host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE proxyhost"',
    ],
})
```

It does not specify a login password for this proxy and it clearly does not work

If you specify this

```
'--proxy-server=socks5://user:password@proxyhost:8000',
```

it gives an error

**net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES**

I tried with https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator build a bridge, but it did not work either.

Prompt please

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`page.authenticate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageauthenticatecredentials) to provide the credentials for your proxy.

For example:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const username = 'johndoe';
  const password = 'qwerty1';

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--proxy-server=socks5://proxyhost:8000',
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.authenticate({
    username,
    password,
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Tested it with Tor ('--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:9050') and it worked flawlessly, thanks!

Comment: Note that there are issues with proxy authentication when accessing HTTPS pages. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3253 You may want to try https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy